# Chroot Jail User | Allow access via ssh shell

Tags: ssh, chroot

How to allow chroot Jail users(sftp) to access terminal through SSH.

The user will placed file via WinSCP (chroot Jail).then on same server login to putty(ssh) there is a script that will launch application for user to work with. As soon the user exit the application, the user will be logout (To restrict access to command prompt)

Currently system is not allowing chrooted user to access shell via putty on same server.

Comment: Yes use docker: It does a bit more that `chroot`, including network name spaces.

Comment: What OS is this. Please make the question clear: What OS are they starting on?, what OS are the `ssh` to?, Which one has the `chroot`?

Comment: An answer "yes" might not be very useful to you.  If you want to know "how to", then maybe show what you changed in your config to enable the chroot jail. Also look in `/var/log/auth.log` to see if it lists an error when you try to login.  If you find one then you can include that information too.  You can [edit] your question to include more information.